@if not working as expected after angular 17 update
the @if is not working as expected
On interpolating isLoggedIn outside its true but inside the if its false and always showing Login because of this
Please Correct me if there is any issue with this implementation
     @if(!isLoggedIn) {
      <div
     <a href="/login">
            <p>Login</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      }


you are missing the closing tag mate:
  @if(!isLoggedIn) {
    <div>
        <p>Login</p>
    </div>
  }



on this div -> <div

Why are you using html after the 3 back-quotes? The code you typed is not (only) html, so angular or javascript seems more appropriate.

Here's the correct code, you were missing > for the first div
@if(!isLoggedIn) {
    <div>
        <a href="/login">
            <p>Login</p>
        </a>
    </div>
}

